# Java SynchronizedCounter does not work as expected

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a class

```
class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int i = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        i++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        i--;
    }

    public synchronized int getValue() {
        return i;
    }
}
```

which is used like that:

```
public class CounterTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SynchronizedCounter c = new SynchronizedCounter();
        Thread d = new Thread(new D(c));
        Thread e = new Thread(new E(c));
        d.start();
        e.start();
        System.out.println(c.getValue());           
    }
}
```

where class D is implemented as follows:

```
class D implements Runnable {
    private SynchronizedCounter counter;

    D(SynchronizedCounter counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        counter.increment();
    }
}
```

Class E has only one different line in comparison to the class D

```
 counter.decrement();
```

in it's run method.

I would expect to have always 0 printed because the methods of the SynchronisedCounter class are all synchronised, however I get 1 sometimes.
Could you explain me please what is wrong with this code?
When I run d.start() and e.start() in synchronized(c) block then it works as expected, the same happens when I add d.join() after d.start() and e.join() after e.start().

Comment: Threads don't spawn instantly. It takes some time

Comment: Threads run concurrently, that's the whole point. So if D increaments first, then the main thread gets the value, then E decrements, you get 1 on the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're making a lot of assumptions about threads which do not hold true.
The two main assumptions of yours which do not hold true are these:

- All threads run at the same speed.
- All threads are started immediately.

The execution sequence is random.
The threads run concurrently.
In the following, sequence means the sequence in which the threads hit `SynchronizedCounter` via the method calls. Because that's what `synchronized` does, it forces concurrent threads into sequential access by guarding it with a monitor (if you don't know what a monitor is, read mutex semaphore instead, it's different, but for this explanation the difference isn't important).
You can expect any of the following three outputs:

- `0` in case the sequence was D, E, main; or E, D, main; or main, D, E; or main, E, D.
- `1` in case the sequence was D, main, E
- `-1` in case the sequence was E, main, D.

## Threads are not started immediately

When you invoke `new Thread().start()`, the `Thread` becomes runnable. But it is up to the scheduler to decide when the thread actually gets CPU time. And that depends on factors outside the realm of a program's influence, sometimes even outside the realm of a VM's influence. For example, how close any of the existing threads is to being preempted because of exhausting its timeslice, or whether idle CPU cores are available right now.

## Threads run at different speeds

The speed of a thread is determined by various factors which are outside the realm of a program's influence. For example, if the thread wants to access data, whether that data is cached or not, and in which cache it is, to give just one example.

The output `-1` is the most unlikely output, but even that output cannot be ruled out completely. And that "unlikely" is also purely based on assumptions made from observations of how virtual machines usually behave, and it is not anything that can be relied upon.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer I understand and agree with all that you wrote, but then I don’t understand what in this case gives me the synchronized keyword in the SynchronizedCounter class?

Comment: It ensures that `i--` and `i++` behave like atomic operations. Imagine how `i--` or `i++` have to be implemented: Read, Update, Write. What if threads race on Read, Update, Write? Say 2 threads A and B call increment() from 0 at the very same time. We would expect 2. Without synchronized, we might get 1 instead. A: Read 0. B: Read 0. A: Update 0->1. B: Update 0->1. A: Write 1. B: Write 1. That's what might happen without synchronized.

Comment: BTW this also means that strictly speaking, in _this_ particular example, `synchronized` is not needed on `getValue()` because `getValue()` is atomic already. However, I would still keep the `synchronized` there, in case future changes would make it non-atomic.

Comment: @BlueLettuce16 Sorry I don't understand your last comment, would you please clarify?

Comment: You wrote, that: "Say 2 threads A and B call increment() from 0 at the very same time. We would expect 2. Without synchronized, we might get 1 instead. A: Read 0. B: Read 0. A: Update 0->1. B: Update 0->1. A: Write 1. B: Write 1. That's what might happen without synchronized." but it happens as well with the synchronized. Ok now I see at the same time, it's clear now, thanks.

Comment: No this does NOT happen with `synchronized`. With `synchronized`, you're guaranteed to have value `2` in this case, when both `increment()` operations finished. Without `synchronized`, you might end up having the value `1` instead of `2` even after both `increment()` operations completed.

Comment: So if we have synchronized and it returned 1 that it means that not both increment() operations finished?

Comment: @ChristianHujer synchronized is absolutely required on getValue(), otherwise there is no guarantee that the main thread will see the latest value, updated by the other thread.

Comment: @JBNizet It is required to see the latest value unless the value is declared volatile. Wouldn't all that absolutely required, but still you got a point there.